# Seeking on Ogg/Opus

Tags: audio, encoding, streaming, ogg, opus

I have ogg-opus audio files each containing a single track (mono) and of fixed sample rate (16kHz). I'm trying to implement seeking on them for streaming. For example, I want to know byte offsets to partially download a file (with HTTP Range) and play only the first 10 seconds, or say from second 10 to second 15. That is, I need to get the the byte offset at any given time position.

Is there a way to do it without loading/decoding an entire file in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there's an exact way to determine the exact byte offset required for a specific time, but [`libopus.op_pcm_seek()`](https://mf4.xiph.org/jenkins/view/opus/job/opusfile-unix/ws/doc/html/group__stream__seeking.html) could be used for decoding once you have the bytes.    Between the varying bit rates, page sizes, and packet durations of Opus files, some guesswork and dynamic calculations seem to be required.  I'm attempting to do the same thing and a few people have asked me to implement it in `OpusStreamDecoder`.  You could look at its underlying [`opus_chunkdecoder.c`](https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/blob/master/src/opus_chunkdecoder.c) and the specific feature request which outlines how this could be achieved:

https://github.com/AnthumChris/opus-stream-decoder/issues/1